# Installation of big .apk take longe time on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, installation, apk

I am writing application for Android. Application size is more then 200 MB. And it take very long time to install on the Android Emulator. I want to know

1. How can I ***speed up installation of huge file*** on Android Emulator.
2. How I can speed up Android Emulator ( for example to give more ***RAM*** for it or to give more ***Internal Memory*** for it ).

My operating system is Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Holy Megabytes! Batman, what kinda application is this?

Comment: Holy Cow ! Thats a huge APK ! So what did you do to speed up things ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you have a 200mb APK? I can imagine you'd have some sort of data (it's surely not 200mb of pure code, right?) ?

You could/should remove this and put it on the (virtual) SD card of your emulator. APK size will be lot smaller, no need to keep loading that datafile.

In the end you'd want to do this for release anyway: 200mb is way too big. Release a small(er) APK and make the data available as download.

And if it *is* all code.. well, then you're out of luck.

Comment: It is 200mb of code ... It's a some sort of library that helps to di some actions ... @Nanne if I realy have 200 MB application that must be loaded to the RAM what can I do ? If I use an Emulator ?

Comment: If it is a library you should place it in it's own APK only used by your app. Then you have to install it only once.

Comment: @Robert: I don't know if you can easily use a library from another APK? I doubt it, but I don't really know. @ ViTo : If you really, really really need that much code, you probably just have to wait for it to load.  Keep in mind that the market-limit is quite low. used to be 25 MB, now it is 50 MB. Try and cut down on the  library size. What library is it?!

Comment: @Nanne: You can. APKs that are signed with the same key can enable access sharing which makes all internal interfaces accessible to the other APK.

Comment: Interesting, and a possible sollution, although I'm still skeptical about the need for all of this :)

Answer (score 1):

```
How can I speed up installation of huge file on Android Emulator.
```

I don't think there's anything you can do to speed up the installation. 200mb is a ridiculously huge APK.

```
 How I can speed up Android Emulator ( for example to give more RAM for 
it or to give more Internal Memory for it ).
```

When you create the AVD (or choose to edit it later), you can specify the amount of memory it has.

See reference here: [Managing Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html)